# [Help]: Multi Line with d3.nest() not rendering lines

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I am trying to render multiple lines with x, y axis as 1st, 2nd values of each array out of 5 arrays within datarow dataset. i want to generate 3 different lines each for 0, 15, 1007 values of 3rd elements in all 5 arrays by nesting through each of the 3rd element in the datarow dataset.

What i tried: https://jsfiddle.net/data_x/23143n3r/

I followed http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/d8be922a10cb0b148cd5.

The important code:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d,i){return x(datarow[i][0]);})
            .y(function(d,i){return y(datarow[i][1]);})
            .interpolate("linear");


  //Nest the entries 
 var nest = d3.nest()   
              .key( function(d) { return d[2]})    
              .entries(datarow);  

 //Loop through each d[2]
    nest.forEach(
        function(d,i)
        {

            svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")               
                .attr("d",  line(d.values[0][2]))
                .style("stroke-width", 1)
                .style("stroke", "steelblue")
                .style("fill", "none")
        }
    );
```

In above code, d.values[0] returns all the array elements. As i want to plot multiple lines for 3rd values in each array, i am returning 3rd element in each array. But, i am still not able to figure out why nothing is being rendered.

Any help or hints are appreciated,

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a friend,

Problem is at

```
      `var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d,i){return x(datarow[i][0]);})
        .y(function(d,i){return y(datarow[i][1]);})
        .interpolate("linear");`
```

whereas it should be like

```
                       d3.svg.line()
                             .x(function(d){return x(d[0]);})
                              .y(function(d){return y(d[1]);})
                              .interpolate("linear");`
```

Line x,y accesory functions takes array of values as input not single values.